# Ember computed property doesn't work

Tags: ember.js, javascript-framework, handlebars.js

I have a view which has a computed property. When the dependency gets updated the observer fires properly, but the computed property does not. What could be the reasons?

In the handlebars:

```
{{#view viewName currencyBinding="changingValue"}}
    {{view.prefix}}
{{/view}}
```

In the view:

```
prefix: (function() {
  //does not get called!!! 
  console.log('computed property fired');
  return this.get('currency');
}).property('currency')

observeCurrency: (function() {
  //gets called!
  return console.log('observer fired');
}).observes('currency')
```

The observer is fired when the 'changingValue' is updated but the property does not! 
Also if I set the 'prefix' in the observer:

```
observeCurrency: (function() {
    //gets called!
    console.log('observer fired');
    return this.set('prefix', this.get('currency'));
}).observes('currency')
```

My html does not get updated unless I do an explicit rerender of the view. Why is that happening?

Comment: unless I'm missing something you don't have to wrap your computed property like that, it should be something like `computedPropertyName: function { ... }.property('dependency')`

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say what's going on without all your code, but let's see...
So perhaps you should remove that wrapping around your computed property as I said in the comment, so your view would have a property that looks somewhat like this:

```
SomeView: Em.View.extend({
    // other stuff...
    prefix: function() {
        console.log('prefix being called');
        // code that returns something goes here
    }.property('currency'),
    // other stuff...
})
```

Now to what I believe to be the problem, I've made a fiddle that simulates this scenario in which you indicate which currency you want, and the computed property has a logic to determine what is the prefix. (You can see the source [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/MmWk2/69/)).

In your code, when you bind `changingValue`, you're not specifying where this property coming from, you're passing a path that Ember is not able to resolve into a property of an object in your application. In the fiddle that I wrote, note that the property `changingValue` belongs to my application (which I named SomeApp). Then the path to this property is `SomeApp.changingValue`, and my binding in handlebars ends up being:

`{{view SomeApp.SomeView currencyBinding="SomeApp.changingValue"}}'`

Also, note that on that fiddle, I created a child view which binds its `content` property with the value of currency coming from the parent view. I've only added it there so you can see how the path would be if the property `changingValue` in *your code* belongs to a parent view.

I hope this helps.